# NSDatePicker returns default date even when date is set programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdatepicker

I have a `datePicker` instance which is linked to the `IBOutlet`.

```
@interface SomeClass() {

    __weak IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
}
```

Now in my `awakeFromNib` method I am setting the `minimumDate`, `maximumDate` and `date` property

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    [datePicker setMinimumDate:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*10]];
    [datePicker setMaximumDate:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*10]];
    [datePicker setDate:datePicker.minimumDate];

    NSLog(@"%@", datePicker.date);
    //Logs Correct Value
}
```

When I log `datePicker.date` after setting it in `awakeFromNib` method, it gives correct value. Till now so good.

Now when I try to get the date value after the view is initialized, for ex, on a button click event, it gives me the default value which is current date value.

```
- (IBAction)aButtonTouchUpInsideEvent:(UIButton *)button {
    NSLog(@"%@", datePicker.date);
    //Logs [NSDate date] value
}
```

I want to know why it is not giving me the value which I set in `awakeFromNib` method. I tried searching for this issue but no luck.

Comment: why awakeFromNib instead of viewDidLoad?

Comment: @SarrY and whats the delegate? As per the Apple documentation and UIKit Framework, there is no delegate for UIDatePicker.

Comment: @Sanandrea because it is an UIView and not an UIViewController

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala Where you alloc datePicker ?

Comment: Is this view utilised in one of your ViewControllers? Why don't you try to set the datePicker property in viewDidLoad of a ViewController?

Comment: What happens if you add `[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerDidChangeDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];` and trace value changes?

Comment: Yes I tried this, but it doesn't get called when you set it programatically.

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala and what about KVO?

Comment: Surprisingly, the observer is not called at all!

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala so maybe you getting some another, possible new instance somewhere? Could you log how many times you create that view?

Comment: No its being created only once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73251/discussion-between-azat-and-burhanuddin-sunelwala).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You value is overridden at some time by system. You can move your code to `-willMoveToSuperview:`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    NSString *dateStr = @"Tue, 25 May 2010 12:53:58 +0000";
    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE, d LLLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
    [myPicker setDate:date];
```

then try to get the date time from picker may be there is some issue with setting time

Comment: As I have mentioned in the  question, it gives correct time while setting it in awakeFromNib method.